# Meteor Routes & Sessions -> How to coordinate

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Meteor Question: what is the best way to implement real sessions?
I have a normal login page with statistics. No issues there.

Now, I want people to be able to check-in with specific urls; assume they later 
hit a url like http://localhost:3000/checkin/area1

How can I coordinate that with their login?

I have a route for the checkin:

```
Router.route('/checkin/:_id', function () {
  var req = this.request;
  var res = this.response;

  this.userId = 'steve';  //TODO: Need way to pull userId
  if (!this.userId) {
    res.end('Please login first');
  } else {
    //Verify correct area
    //Verify that haven't check before
    var lastCheckin = checkins.find({ user: this.userId, visited: this.params._id });
    if (lastCheckin.count() == 0) {
        //we haven't checkedin yet
        checkins.insert({ user: this.userId, visited: this.params._id, createdAt: new Date() })
        res.end('Checkin '+this.userId+' for '+this.params._id);
    } else {
        console.log('already checked in '+lastCheckin.createdAt);
        res.end(this.userId+' already visited '+this.params._id);
    }
  }
}, {where: 'server'});
```

Things I've tried:

- Persistent session: But that doesn't work because request is not coming from the main page, so no session variable to pull.
- Pull cookie in Request (since Persistent session seems to have 1). The original login doesn't appear to have the request object, so I don't know where to get that.
- Others (diff situations) have shown a Meteor.user() inside a route, but the software complains that it can only be used inside a method.  What can be used inside a route?

What else can I try?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am not sure if this will help exactly but.

If you are on /myPage, then you have an event that runs:

```
Router.go('/yourPage');
Session.set('yourVariable', "yourValue");
```

You will be able to access the session variable (yourVariable) in /yourPage (and yourPage's code).

Comment: Where does the Session.set go?
I currently have that already set when they login.  But for the /yourPage example, when does it get included in the request?

If I look at the page returned from /checkin, there is not javascript or anything, so there is nothing on the client side checking for any sessions.  

Thanks.